# distcp: copy file from hdfs to s3 (How to use in scala or java)

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, emr, distcp

I am trying to copy huge files from hdfs to s3 via distcp through the following code:

```
val files:Array[String] = new Array[String](2)
files(0) = "/****/in.zip"

val in =  new Path(new URI("/**/in.zip"))
val out = new Path(new URI("***/out.zip"))
var distcpOpt = new DistCpOptions(in,out)
ToolRunner.run(new DistCp(new Configuration(),distcpOpt), files)
```

I tried to do something similar to [this link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp).

anyone did this before, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

1- the files array should has two value: First one for the input and the second one for the output.

2- distcpOpt does not need to have any value (empty string is enough)

3- be sure from s3 path

Comment: Any chance that you could share the code that worked for you now?